# Where asp.net framework 2 website output directory folders and files?

Tags: asp.net

Virtual folder in IIS can directly set to a working asp.net directory, this website project I am working on is set in IIS as well. Where is the generated output folder for this project when debugging? I couldn't find it anywhere inside the working folder. There is no debug/release obj folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files